# Implementing Swagger Authorization with Identity Server 4 asp.net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, swagger, identityserver4

Trying to implement Swagger Authorization with identity server 4. Getting errors but don't know where I am doing wrong.

**Identity Server setting**

```
public IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        var client = new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                 ClientId = ConstantValue.ClientId,
                ClientName = ConstantValue.ClientName,
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RequireConsent = false,
                RedirectUris =           { string.Format("{0}/{1}", Configuration["IdentityServerUrls:ClientUrl"], "assets/oidc-login-redirect.html"), string.Format("{0}/{1}", Configuration["IdentityServerUrls:ClientUrl"], "assets/silent-redirect.html") },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { string.Format("{0}?{1}", Configuration["IdentityServerUrls:ClientUrl"] , "postLogout=true") },
                AllowedCorsOrigins =     { Configuration["IdentityServerUrls: ClientUrl"] },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    ConstantValue.ClientDashApi
                },
                IdentityTokenLifetime=120,
                AccessTokenLifetime=120
            },
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "swaggerui",
                ClientName = "Swagger UI",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

                RedirectUris =
                {
                    string.Format("{0}/{1}", Configuration["IdentityServerUrls:ClientApiUrl"], "swagger/oauth2-redirect.html"),
                    string.Format("{0}/{1}", Configuration["IdentityServerUrls:ClientApiUrl"], "swagger/o2c.html")
                },
                AllowedCorsOrigins =     { Configuration["IdentityServerUrls: ClientApiUrl"] },

                AllowedScopes = {ConstantValue.ClientDashApi},
            },
        };
        return client;
    }
```

**API Codes**

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
                {
                    Type = "oauth2",
                    Flow = "implicit",
                    AuthorizationUrl = "http://localhost:44305/connect/authorize",
                    TokenUrl = "http://localhost:44305/connect/token",
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                    {
                        { "mero-rental-client-api", "mero-rental-client-api" }

                    }
                });
            });


app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Mero Rental API V1");
                options.OAuthClientId("swaggerui");
                options.OAuthAppName("Swagger UI");
            });
```

This is the redirect URL

```
http://localhost:44305/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fresponse_type%3Dtoken%26client_id%3Dswaggerui%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A44333%252Fswagger%252Foauth2-redirect.html%26scope%3Dmero-rental-client-api%26state%3DV2VkIEphbiAwOSAyMDE5IDE0OjUzOjMzIEdNVCsxMTAwIChBdXN0cmFsaWFuIEVhc3Rlcm4gRGF5bGlnaHQgVGltZSk%253D
```

This is the error I am getting in the console.
On the browser.

[image]
[image: added new navigation page]

Reference

https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/ASPNET-Core-Swagger-UI-Authorization-using-IdentityServer4

https://dave.vanherten.ca/2017/03/swagger-identityserver4-part2/

Comment: request to issue a token for accessing a web api fails because of unauthorized client. check if the client details in api project is correct.

Comment: I am able to login now. But page doesn't redirect to swagger api page after login

Answer (score 1):

You configure the RedirectUris for  `Client` with `RedirectUris = { string.Format("{0}/{1}", Configuration["IdentityServerUrls:ClientUrl"], "swagger/o2c.html") }`, this generates `http://localhost:4200/swagger/o2c.html`. But for your request, it sends requesturl with `http://localhost:44333/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html`.

Try to check your client configuration and change it to `http://localhost:4200/swagger/o2c.html`.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {            
        RedirectUri = "http://localhost:4200/swagger/o2c.html",
    });
```

Comment: I am able to login. But after login the page doen't redirect. Can you please let me know.

Comment: @SanJaisy Have you resolved your previous issue? In my memory, your original issue is related with `redirecturl`.

Comment: I have resolve the invalid url issue. Now I am able to login with identity server successfully. But not able to redirect back to swagger UI. Getting the error as above

Comment: @SanJaisy Please accept the answer if it resolves your issue or share us your solution and repost new thread for your new issue. Please avoid editing your original post which will mark suggestions confused.